# Format every table in PowerPoint 2013 presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Apologies for a badly researched question, but I have little knowledge of VBA in general and VBA in PowerPoint in particular and am stuck with what are probably basic concepts.

I'm trying to conditionally format all tables in my presentation, and am adapting [this code from a SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1014035/conditional-formatting-of-powerpoint-table) for my problem.

I've come up with this basic macro:

```
Sub FormatTheTable(oTbl As Table)
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    With oTbl
    For x = 1 To .Rows.Count
    For y = 1 To .Columns.Count
        If .Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.HasText Then
            If CDbl(.Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) > 0 Then
                .Cell(x, y).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next    ' Column
    Next    ' Row
    End With    ' otbl
End Sub

Sub DoIT()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTable Then
                FormatTheTable (shp.Table)
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

End Sub
```

I don't think I'm calling the `FormatTheTable` function correctly, but I have no idea how it would be done correctly. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
FormatTheTable (shp.Table)
```

Should be:

```
FormatTheTable shp.Table
```

Because you are not calling a procedure of type Function which returns a value but a Sub which does not. If it were a function, this would have been ok:

```
myValue = FormatTheTable (shp.Table)
```

Also this line looks a bit odd:

```
If CDbl(.Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) > 0 Then
```

So you're checking each cell for the existence of text and if there is text, you're trying to convert the text to a number? That will raise an error. What are you trying to test for in that line?

Comment: Tagging on @JamieG's answer here: the code's checking the value of the text to see if it's greater than 0 but it'll error if the text is alpha rather than numeric. Change it to:  If CDbl(Val(.Cell(x, y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)) > 0 Then